# Is It Possible To Recover Deleted Partition in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, data-recovery

I was a windows 8.1 user, when i was installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my system there was four partition and for the installation purpose i select installation type "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and my all partition are gone and its turn into one partition. Is there any possibility to recover my old partition or recover old data. please help.